# Number of groups of given order up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading in MSE that, up to isomorphism,  there are 2 groups of order 45. 
How do we know that? 
Is there any way of calculating how many groups of order 10,15 etc. exist up to isomorphism?

Comment: Do you know Sylow theorems in group theory?

Comment: Yes. I know three theorems of sylow and that means only one sylow 3 and sylow 5 subgroup.

Comment: But I am asking a general way.would sylow theorem be enough for all orders?

Comment: Or "special orders " only?

Comment: It's easy to count the abelian groups of this order by the [classification of finite abelian groups](http://torus.math.uiuc.edu/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf).  From there, it suffices to show that there are no *non-abelian* groups of this order.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263885/constructions-of-the-smallest-nonabelian-group-of-odd-order) is tangentially relevant.

Comment: A lot depends on the order. No one knows how many groups there are of order $2^{16}$, but it's easy to find the number of groups of order $2^{16}+1$.

Comment: @ Gerry myerson  And what is that way?

Comment: @low, it doesn't work if you leave a space between the at-sign and the name. But $2^16+1$ is prime, so there's only one group (up to isomorphism) of that order.

Comment: @Gerry myerson we don't have any way to know if that's prime. Do we?

Comment: Given any positive integer, there are plenty of ways to know whether or not it is prime. But this particular number, $2^{16}+1$, we know it's prime if we know our math history. It is a "Fermat prime" – look it up!

Comment: @Gerry myerson I know this number is prime. I mean to say is there any general way to know if a large number is prime or not

Comment: @low, there is a whole industry devoted to primality testing. People have written books on the topic, so I won't write one here, but suggest you check out the literature on the topic. Well, maybe I can put it this way: whether you can know whether a large number is prime or not depends on how large the number is, on other characteristics of the number, and on the resources at your disposal.

Comment: @Gerry myerson how would you know this is prime ----982,451,653

Comment: @low, I suggested you check out the literature on primality testing. Have you done that?

Comment: @Gerry myerson I read about Miller Rabin test in Wikipedia and saw video in you tube.it appears more like algorithms which are not handy often.

Comment: Keep reading. There are plenty of good algorithms. With the right hardware and software, it is routine nowadays to test 1000-digit numbers for primality.

Comment: @Gerry myerson deleted

Answer (score 2):

As you say, by Sylow theorems a group $\;G\;$ of order $\;45\;$ has one unique subgroup $\;P\;$ or order $\;3^2=9\;$ and one unique subgroup $\;Q\;$ of order $\;5\;$ , which means $\;P,\,Q\lhd G\;$ . Also, both $\;P,\,Q\;$ are abelian and so is their product, which generates their direct product since $\;P\cap Q=\{1\}\;$ , and from all this it follows that

$$G=PQ=P\times Q$$

and $\;G\;$ is thus **always** abelian. Since there are two groups up to isomorphism of order $\;p^2\;$ for any prime $\;p\;$ , we get two unique (up to isomorphism) different groups of order $\;45\;$ (both abelian, again):

$$G_1=C_9\times C_5\;\;,\;\;\;G_2=C_3\times C_3\times C_5\cong C_3\times C_{15}$$

The above is a particular case of the general: if $\;p<q\;$ are two primes such that $\;p\,\nmid\,q-1\;$ , then there are two unique groups of prder $\;p^2\cdot q\;$ up to isomorphism

Comment: How do you know that p intersection Q ={1}

Comment: Can you please tell me where would I find more on this? in easy way !

Comment: @lowiq We have that $\;P\cap Q=1\;$ because any element in the intersection  must divide both $\;p\;$ and $\;q\;$ , and these two are different **prime** numbers... About more exercises: any book in group theory surely will contain some exercises of this, and in the internet there must be thousands of sites...