# Group of order $22$ is generated by two elements

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am trying to solve the below problem. I think this problem has been addressed on this website before, but I'd really like to work through the details myself without reading a prepared solution.

> Let $G$ be a group of order $22$ and $x,y$ elements of $G$ where $x \neq e$ and $y \neq x^n$ for any $n$. Prove that $G$ is generated by $x$ and $y$.

The first thing I thought to do was use Lagrange's theorem. Any element of $G$ must have order dividing $|G| = 22$. The possibilities are $1,2,11,22$. As $x \neq e$, $|x| \neq 1$. As $y$ is not equal to a power of $x$, $G$ cannot be a cyclic group of order $22$ generated by $x$, so $|x| \neq 22$. This leaves only $|x| = 2$ or $|x| = 11$. It also means that $y \neq e$, or else there would be a power of $x$ which is equal to $y$ (since $x$ has finite order). If $G$ were cyclic generated by $y$, then $x = y^m$ for some $m$ so $y = x^{-m}$, which is not allowed, so $y$ also does not have order $22$. So both $x$ and $y$ have order $2$ or order $11$.

I have also previously proved that a group of even order has an element of order $2$. If both $x$ and $y$ had order $11$, I don't think this would be possible. The product $xy$ has order equal to (if I'm not mistaken) $\text{lcm}(x,y)$, which has to be at least $11$. This is circular reasoning because I'm presupposing that $x$ and $y$ are the generators of the group, but I think I can say that if $\langle x, y \rangle$ is the group generated by $x$ and $y$, it certainly cannot have an element of order $2$ if $x$ and $y$ both have order $11$. I think I would also run out of elements if both $x$ and $y$ had order $2$. The main group I know of elements of order $2$ is the Klein-four group, which is generated by two elements of order $2$ (and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$. So my sense is that one of $x$ or $y$ must have order $11$ and the other order $2$.

I'm a bit stuck on this point, but would appreciate some direction on how to proceed.

Comment: It is false in general that if $x=y^m$ then $y=x^{-m}$. Note that $x^{-m}=(y^m)^{-m} =y^{m(-m)}=y^{-m^2}$. This equals $y$ if and only if $-m^2\equiv 1\pmod{|y|}$. And you could have a cyclic group generated by $y$, with $x=y^2$, for example.

Comment: I guess a "top-down" proof could be made using the fact that the only groups of order $22$ are $\Bbb Z_{22}$ and $D_{11}$. Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2821718/104041) to get to that point. This might be nuking it though.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the size of the product of two subgroups? $|HK|=|H|\,|K|/|H\cap K|$.

Comment: It is false, in general, that the order of a product equals the lcm of the orders of the terms.

Comment: If this weren't true, you could find two such elements $x,y$ that did not generate the group, so would be contained in a maximal subgroup of $G$. So for it to be true, every pair of such elements cannot be contained in any maximal subgroup. But then that means $\langle x\rangle$ must always be maximal. So you're attempting to prove: **every cyclic subgroup is maximal**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Use $y\notin\langle x\rangle$ to consider $\langle y\rangle \cap\langle x\rangle =\{e\}$. What possible orders could $x,y$ each have? Use Lagrange's Theorem and the fact that

[$$|HK|\cdot |H\cap K|=|H|\cdot \lvert K\rvert $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168942/104041)

for any $H,K\le G$ and any group $G$.

Also $4\nmid 22$ and $11^2>22$.

---

Alternatively, use . . .

[Question on groups of order $pq$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/365261/104041)

. . . to determine the group is $D_{11}$ (because it is not cyclic) and proceed from there.

Comment: The downvote here is pretty petty.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Say the elements $x,y$ are of orders $2,11$.

Then consider $\langle x,y\rangle $.

You might also have two elements of order $2$, but you can argue the same way...

Comment: In the problem the elements $x,y$ are given.

Comment: I know,  at first I had read the title and overlooked that.   @Stephen

Comment: I don’t understand how this “hint” gives any useful information.

Comment: It's trivial that $x$ and $y$ then generate the group.   @Stephen

Comment: Username checks out, I guess :D