# Notation: What is $C(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, quotient-group

$G$ is the order $55$ group described by $G=\langle x,y \mid x^{11}=y^5=1, yxy^{-1}=x^4\rangle$. I am tasked with showing $|G/C(G)|=5$, but I don't know what $C(G)$ is supposed to be. It can't be the centre, as the centre is trivial - we need $|C(G)|=11$, but I cant think of what else it could be. Any advice?

Comment: I think the best thing would be to ask the person who gave that exercise. And if it's from a book, the notation should appear there. Maybe that's the derived (commutator) subgroup of $G$, but it's just my guess.

Comment: @Mark It's from a past paper from several years ago.... so I've no idea who wrote it.

Comment: Well, the derived subgroup of $G$ is indeed equal to $\langle x\rangle$, so it has order $11$. So maybe my guess was right.

Comment: The only elements of order $11$ are powers of $x$, so whatever $C(G)$ should mean, it must compute to $\left< x \right>$.

Comment: Yeah I think derived/commutator subgroup makes sense, especially given the notation $C$.

Comment: $G$ is a group of order $pq$, with $p\mid q-1$. So it is either the cyclic group $C_{pq}$, or a non-abelian semidirect product, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1502186/structure-of-groups-of-order-pq-where-p-q-are-distinct-primes). So you can write down all subgroups you need, and your group is the  nonabelian one.